# Mostrar la próxima fecha de cumpleaños MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, concat

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta que me muestre la próxima fecha de cumpleaños de la persona que especifico en el WHERE.
El problema es que con mi código, solamente me muestra el próximo cumpleaños de personas que aún no han complido años este año, por ejemplo, si la persona cumplió años en enero 2021, me mostrará que su siguiente fecha es enero 2021 cuando debería de ser enero 2022

De momento tengo esto:

```
SELECT CONCAT(nombre, ' ' ,apellido) as 'nombre_apellido', edad, 
CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-', MONTH(fecha_nacimiento), '-', DAY(fecha_nacimiento)) AS 'Proxima_fecha_de_cumpleanios' 
FROM datos_clientes WHERE numero_de_telefono = 22222222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el año actual y suma uno si la fecha (tupla mes y año) ya pasó.

```
SELECT CONCAT(nombre, ' ' ,apellido) as 'nombre_apellido'
     , edad
     , concat_ws( '-'
                , year(curdate()) 
                  + if( (month(fecha_nacimiento),day(fecha_nacimiento)) < (month(curdate()),day(curdate()))
                      , 1
                      , 0 
                      )
                , month(fecha_nacimiento)
                , day(fecha_nacimiento)
                ) AS 'Proxima_fecha_de_cumpleanios' 
  FROM datos_clientes 
  WHERE numero_de_telefono = 22222222
```

De hecho, puedes quitar el if y aprovechar la auto-conversión del booleano de la comparación:

```
year(curdate()) 
+ ( ( month(fecha_nacimiento), day(fecha_nacimiento) )
  < ( month(curdate()       ), day(curdate()       ) )
  )
```

Comment: Habría que comparar la fecha completa. Si pruebas esta consulta con una fecha de nacimiento como esta: `2021-04-11`   te muestra esa misma fecha, cuando debería mostrar `2022-04-11` porque el día 11 ya pasó.

Comment: @A. Cedano: Depende del criterio, en tal caso se compara con `<=`. Si es para mandar a hacer un pastel de cumpleaños, hoy podría ser tarde; si es para enviar una felicitación, tal vez sea preferible recibirla hoy.

Answer (score 3):

Lo más seguro para este caso es determinar en una sub-consulta la fecha de aniversario del año actual (`current_anniv`), así como la fecha de aniversario del próximo año (`next_anniv`)  y luego elegir una u otra en un [`CASE ... WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) que compare si `current_anniv` es mayor que la fecha actual.

Así no habrá lugar a ningún equívoco.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(nombre, ' ' ,apellido) as 'nombre_apellido',
    edad, 
    CASE
        WHEN t.current_anniv >= CURDATE() 
            THEN t.current_anniv
            ELSE t.next_anniv
        END AS next_dob
FROM
    (
       SELECT 
           fecha_nacimiento + INTERVAL (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(fecha_nacimiento)) YEAR AS current_anniv,
           fecha_nacimiento + INTERVAL (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(fecha_nacimiento)) + 1 YEAR AS next_anniv
       FROM datos_clientes 
           WHERE numero_de_telefono = 22222222
    ) as t;
```

#### Nota de edición

La consulta anterior no funcionaba del todo bien. En una fecha como `2018-04-20` devolvía una fecha del próximo año `2022-04-18`. Con esta nueva versión, al obtener las eventuales fechas de aniversario entre el presente año y el siguiente, ese problema queda solventado.

Comment: @Sal tienes razón. He mejorado el código. Creo que lo más simple es obtener la actual fecha de aniversario y la próxima y luego comparar.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes valerte de una sentencia `case` para evaluar si ya cumplió años este año o no, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT CONCAT(  case
                  when MONTH(fecha_nacimiento) < MONTH(CURDATE()) then YEAR(CURDATE()) + 1
                  when MONTH(fecha_nacimiento) > MONTH(CURDATE()) then YEAR(CURDATE())
                  when DAY(fecha_nacimiento) <= DAY(CURDATE()) then YEAR(CURDATE()) + 1
                  else YEAR(CURDATE())
                end
              , '-', MONTH(fecha_nacimiento)
              , '-', DAY(fecha_nacimiento)
             ) AS 'Proxima_fecha_de_cumpleanios' 
  FROM datos_clientes 
 WHERE numero_de_telefono = 22222222
```

He dejado las condiciones de esa manera esperando que sea fácil de comprender la idea detrás. Puedes lograr el mismo resultado valiéndote de la función `if()`.

La condición podría reescribirse de muchas maneras, entre mis preferidas:

```
case
  when MONTH(fecha_nacimiento) * 100 + DAY(fecha_nacimiento) > MONTH(CURDATE()) * 100 + DAY(CURDATE()) then YEAR(CURDATE)
  else YEAR(CURDATE) + 1
end
```

o esta:

```
YEAR(CURDATE) + if(MONTH(fecha_nacimiento) * 100 + DAY(fecha_nacimiento) < MONTH(CURDATE()) * 100 + DAY(CURDATE()), 1, 0)
```

Debes pensar qué se qué se considera la próxima fecha de cumpleaños el día del cumpleaños de este año, si es hoy, o es el cumpleaños del próximo año, pues las condiciones del case son distintas para ambos casos.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Es justo lo que estaba buscando hacer y no podia... Muchas gracias!!!